# MySQL query for "Sales Report by Country and State/Province"

Tags: mysql

A client needs a sales report by country state/province. There is an orders table that stores the customer's country and state/province, and there is an orders_products table that stores the order to product association and the product's price.

The client wants the following statistics per country & state/province: total sales, % sales, avg order value.

I hope I have provided enough information. If you need anything else, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: So how much can I bill per hour for this?

Comment: For total sales and average order is the quantity of items sold where

For % sales is this the percentage per country or how much is sold out of total

Comment: we're gonna need a fair amount of more information.  Can you provide the table descriptions for the two tables you mention?  Also, please show your work on the query so far, and we can help you get it to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

== Assumed Tables ==

orders (id, country_id, state_id)

orders_products (id, order_id, product_id, price)

== Queries ==

Total sales:

```
SELECT country_id, state_id, SUM(price)
FROM orders_products op, orders o 
WHERE op.order_id = o.id 
GROUP BY country_id, state_id
```

Average Sale Amount:

```
SELECT country_id, state_id, AVG(price) * COUNT(order_id) 
FROM orders_products op, orders o 
WHERE op.order_id = o.id 
GROUP BY country_id, state_id, order_id
```

The % of total sales per state/country:

```
SELECT country_id, state_id, SUM(price) * 100 /
    (SELECT SUM(price) FROM orders_products op2) 
FROM orders_products op, orders o 
WHERE op.order_id = o.id 
GROUP BY country_id, state_id
```