# Sales report by state in magento

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, magento

I need to get these data from orders
 State name(CA/NY), Gross total, shipping, Status, discounts, net total

i want to select the start date and end date. If some one can give the query that will be enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL query for "Sales Report by Country and State/Province"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105664/mysql-query-for-sales-report-by-country-and-state-province)

Checkout the answer provided by [Justin Giboney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133935/justin-giboney) in the above link and you will get a hint

Comment: That answer is useful in a general sense but is not specific enough for Magento