# Sales report by state in magento in 1.7.0.2

Tags: sql, magento, magento-1.7

There was a solution provided for 1.4 [MySQL query for "Sales Report by Country and State/Province"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105664/mysql-query-for-sales-report-by-country-and-state-province)  unfortunately the table structure has changed. Anyone know a query to order sales by state in 1.7.0.2? I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i came up with:

```
SELECT
    sales_flat_order_address.region
    , count(*)
FROM 
    `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` 
        ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id 
        AND sales_flat_order_address.address_type="shipping" 
GROUP BY
    sales_flat_order_address.region
```